# Rails: Can't run DB Rake on OS X 10.6 because gem SQL lite cannot be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Here's my error message when I do a DB rake:

> Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0)' in
>   any of the gem sources listed in your
>   Gemfile.

I've tried Installing xCode 4.0.2

Commands:

```
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby 
sudo gem update --system 
sudo gem update rails 
sudo gem update sqlite3-ruby
```

Gem list produces:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.8, 2.2.2)
actionpack (3.0.8, 2.2.2)
activemodel (3.0.8)
activerecord (3.0.8, 2.2.2)
activeresource (3.0.8, 2.2.2)
activesupport (3.0.8, 3.0.6, 2.2.2)
arel (2.0.10)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.14)
erubis (2.6.6)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.8, 2.2.2)
railties (3.0.8)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.3)
rubygems-update (1.8.5, 1.8.4, 1.3.1)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
```

Any suggestions? I'm on Max OS X 10.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing:

> sudo gem i sqlite3

If you check the man via:

> gem help commands

The "i" stands for install, sort of a short cut. Doing this after running the bundle update & all the core updates cased Ruby's rake to work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work if you add sqlite to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

And run:

```
$ bundle update
```